Unable to access a public API end point that requires Authorization code grant type
I have an application A hosted in AWS and its API end point, I have another application B hosted in Google Cloud and its API end point.
I have a challenge to access my A application endpoint from my B application.
Because my A application endpoint can only be accessed using OAuth 2.0(implicit and Authorization code grant), But my application B does not support Implicit and Authorization code grant. I cannot make any changes in either of the applications.
Hence, I am planning to build a custom application C that should be acting as a connector between A and B.
So that my B application will always call the C application and my C application will in turn connect with application A on behalf of  Application B and exchange the tokens accordingly.
Not sure how to get started on this topic.
Could you please suggest any thoughts on how to achieve this or any other approaches are welcome

What does 'connect with application A on behalf of Application B' mean. Why does application B exist in this scenario if you cant just connect to Application A directly.
